# Instantiating object in child; assign to parent class variable

Tags: php, class, oop

What is the proper way to do this:

```
// child
class B extends A {

   function __construct() {
        $this->object = new B; /// (or `new self` ?)
   }

}

// parent
class A {
   protected $object;

       private static function {
           $object = $this->object;
           // use the new instance of $object
       }
}
```

When I try this in code, I get this error:

`Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context`  What am I doing wrong?  (this is referring to Class `A` instance)

Comment: Did you even try to **[SEARCH](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Fatal+error%3A+Using+%24this+when+not+in+object+context%22)** ?!?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `$this` in a static method; $this can only be used in an instantiated object.

you will have to change $object to a static and call it using `self::$object`

```
class B extends A {

   function __construct() {
        self::$object = new B;
   }

}

// parent
class A {
   static protected $object;

   private static function doSomething(){
       $object = self::$object;
       // use the new instance of $object
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't believe that bad error.  That's a basic principle.  Marking you correct when the time allows it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `$this` to refer to the object in a static method, so you have to change it up a bit. Make `object` a protected static member.

```
class A {
  protected static $object;

   private static function() {
       $object = self::$object;
       // use the new instance of $object
   }
}
```